# change datatable cell background function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, datatable

After returning the data for a `datatable`, I want to be able to change the cell background color based on the cell data using a function called `changeCell()`.

```
function changeCell(day)
{
  if(day == "SPAIN")
  {
    return $(nTd).css({'background-color': '#33CC33'});
  }
  if(day == "NEW YORK")
  {
    return $(nTd).css({'background-color': '#AFD645'}); 
  }
  // and so on
}
```

Here is the datatable (simplified as much as possible):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'process/getData.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data); 
    var table = $('#example1').DataTable({  
      "data": jsonObject,
      "columns": [ 
        {
          "data": "DAY_MON",
          "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
          {
            changeCell(oData.DAY_MON); // function call here
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  },
  error: {
    // bunch of error stuff
  }
});
```

However when I call the function, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: nTd is not defined
```

I'm assuming the error is because the function doesn't recognize the `nTd`, but the `nTd` is what I need to return back to the `datatable`.

How can I make this function work?

Comment: `nTd` is not in the scope of your `changeCell` function, have you tried passing it as an argument?

Comment: I have to admit, creating custom functions is not one of my strong suits, and I know I need to master it.  With that said, I'm not really sure how I would pass the nTd.

Comment: I've posted an answer to explain how to perform the argument passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `nTd` is not in the scope of your `changeCell` function, you have to pass it to it as an argument like other one:

```js
"fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
    changeCell(nTd, oData.DAY_MON);
}
```

You'd then change the definition of your function to be:

```js
function changeCell(nTd, day) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sir, you have genius level intellect.  Thank you.  This is what worked for me.  I promise to work on my custom functions.

Comment: My pleasure, all you need to know to start understanding functions and scopes you can find in the [MDN Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) documentation. It has an excellent explanation and examples for scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use jQuery Datatable built in function

```
var dt= $('#example1').DataTable({ 
    'rowCallback': function(row, data, index){
     $(row).find('td:eq(1)').css('color', 'black') //1 is index of your td
  }
});
```

see working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/j1enfpsr/1/)